# R Random Forest: OOB error rate changes when sequence of columns is changed in feature table

Tags: r, random-forest

I am puzzled with the following "behaviour" of RandomForest and wonder, whether this has been experienced by other users - and what I can do to avoid this:
Anything else being equal (and using the same set.seed value), the results of a randomForest model (e.g. its OOB estimate of error rate) changes only by changing the sequence of the features (=columns) of the data table. In the following code, I 
1) run randomForest() once: OOB = 23.06% 
2) randomly change the sequence of the data table
3) run randomForest() again with the changes data table: OOB=22.53%

```
R.version.string
library(randomForest)
library(dplyr)

df <- readRDS("df_feature_list.rds")
head(df)

set.seed(1) 
RF <-  randomForest(Class ~ . , data = df)
RF # OOB error: 23.06%

# randomly swap field order in feature table
df <- df[, sample(names(df))]
head(df)

set.seed(1) 
RF <-  randomForest(Class ~ . , data = df)
RF # OOB error: 22.53%
```

Comment: 23.06 == 22.53, with a margin of error

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the way `randomForest` uses the random seed. It uses the seed to select predictors in the formula during running, based on position of the predictors, not name. Since you use the `.` operator to select all columns in your data frame, the ordering of the predictors is different in your formula call (based on data frame ordering) and while the model selects the same position each iteration, they are actually different columns.

I only show OOB error output below to reduce length of the post, but here is a simple example.

```r
library(randomForest)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(class = c(sample(c("a", "b", "c"), size = 100, replace = T)),
                 x = runif(100),
                 y = runif(100))

set.seed(1)
randomForest(class ~ ., data = df)
#> OOB estimate of  error rate: 75%

# Changing order of columns changes results

set.seed(1)
randomForest(class ~ ., data = df[,c(1,3,2)])
#> OOB estimate of  error rate: 70%

# But if we specify the formula, get the same result as original

set.seed(1)
randomForest(class ~ x + y, data = df[,c(1,3,2)])
#> OOB estimate of  error rate: 75%

# Keeping ordering of data frame but renaming columns doesn't change results

names(df) <- c("class", "y", "x")
set.seed(1)
randomForest(class ~ ., data = df)
#> OOB estimate of  error rate: 75%
```

To get the same behavior every time, you need to either specify the formula explicitly or maintain the same ordering of data frame columns.

Comment: If this answers your question, please consider accepting answer.